# tf.keras how to reuse resnet layers as customize layer in customize model

Tags: tensorflow, keras, customization, layer, resnet

i am search a solution to reuse pre-trained Resnet50 model as a customized sub-layers inside a big customized model.

In my scenario, I use Resnet50 as FCN backbone, and then I will use FCN output result as input to another network layers.(its a pipeline)

you can see my code:
https://github.com/piginzoo/textscanner/blob/master/network/layers/fcn_layer.py
https://github.com/piginzoo/textscanner/blob/master/network/model.py

my question is, i cannot find an example code, to integrate the Resnet50 layers as partial of customized layer in TF 2.0, i search out stackoverflow, TF2.0 offical website and blogs, cannot find a feasible code snippet to demo how to implement such requirement.

but I believe this is a very common paradigm, does anyone ever faces on such problems, and any advices or code demo will be very appreciated.

Comment: all examples is for tf1.x or old keras version , no suitable example for tf 2.0 & tf.keras

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57637985/how-to-change-sequential-model-to-custom-class-model refer this post, i think using the tf.hub resnet50 as input for my customize model maybe is an idea...

Comment: but when i tried, i found i only can get its final output vector, but for FCN i need to get its pool3,pool4,pool5, which are middle layers output.

Answer (score 0):

Finally i found a feasible way, like:

as the code shown, I created a new model who use pre-trained Resnet50's input as his input, and use the 3 "conv_block_out"s as new model's outputs, and in call method, i just call the model as "a layer" style.

for detail, you can refer to my Github for [completed code](https://github.com/piginzoo/textscanner/blob/master/network/layers/fcn_layer.py).

Dummy code:

```
class FCNLayer(Layer):
    def __init__(self, name, resnet50_model):
        super().__init__(name=name)
        resnet50_model.layers.pop()
        resnet50_model.summary()
        self.resnet50_model = resnet50_model

    def build(self, input_image, FILTER_NUM=4):
        layer_names = [
            "conv3_block4_out",  # 1/8
            "conv4_block6_out",  # 1/16
            "conv5_block3_out",  # 1/32
        ]
        layers = [self.resnet50_model.get_layer(name).output for name in layer_names]
        self.FCN_left = Model(inputs=self.resnet50_model.input, outputs=layers)
        ......


    def call(self, input_image, training=True):

        pool3, pool4, pool5 = self.FCN_left(input_image)
        .......
```